# How can I get my captions centered and the text justified with the caption package?

Tags: captions

I am using the caption package for my thesis to get uniform captions since I have longtables and floating tables. Now I was wondering if it is possible to get centered captions (since my graphics and tables are centered) but the text should be justified. I am working with LyX Version 2.3.4.2

`\usepackage[small,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}`

Using justification=centerlast does more or less how I want it to look like, but the last line should not be centered but also justified.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/) Could you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/) that illustrates your problem? I tried to reproduce it myself, but only got [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAy4s.png), which seems to be exactly what you desired as far I understand.

Comment: Why singlelinesheck=off?  It prevents short captions from being centered.  Seer also the margin and width options (page 11).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that solved my problem. I am new to all of this, so I got this code as suggestion to format all my captions uniformly and I just used it without thinking.